# How do I make the Codeschools angular side look similar?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, github

I've tried for quite some time after passing the codeschools "Shaping up with Angular" course to make it work. The last thing I tried was even to copy their source code to make sure that there were no typos on my side and the results vary quite a lot and I don't know what I'm doing wrong at this point.

This is what my site looks like on GitPages:
http://danieboy.github.io/codeschool-shaping-up-with-angular-master/index.html

This is what it looks like on the course website:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe7Ft.png

Anyone able to shed some light on this problem is my hero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual source can be found here: http://discuss.codeschool.io/t/shaping-up-with-angularjs-source-code-demo/5363

It seems that they have a style.css file that is not included in your code. That file specifies layout and appearance for the body tag, the img-thumbnails, img-wrap, small-image, thumbnail classes and others. Right now, you add these classes to elements in your html files, but there is no css stylesheet to define them.

Check out the plunker they share at the above link. You'll need to create a css file that specifies the appropriate styles for these classes and reference it in your index file header.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I knew there had to be one of those somewhere...